# Using BASH, how to increment a number that uniquely only occurs once in most lines of an HTML file?

Tags: bash

The target is always going to be between two characters, 'E' and '/' and there will never be but one occurrence of this combination, e.g. 'E01/' in most lines in the HTML file and will always be between '01' and '90'.

So, I need to programmatically read the file and replace each occurrence of 'Enn/' where 'nn' in 'Enn/' will be between '01' and '90' and must maintain the '0' for numbers '01' to '09' in 'Enn/' while incrementing the existing number by 1 throughout the HTML file.

Is this doable and if so how best to go about it?

Edit: Target lines will be in one or the other formats:

```
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/ProgramName%20S01E01/0/99/0">ProgramName</A>

<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E01/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
```

Comment: Please post some sample data from your HTML file.

Comment: jaypal, thanks for asking.  I've edited the OP adding the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `perl` one-liner to increment the numbers while maintaining the ones with leading 0s.

```
perl -pe 's/E\K([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02d", 1+$1/e' file
```

```
$ cat file
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/ProgramName%20S01E01/0/99/0">ProgramName</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E01/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E59/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E85/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
```

```
$ perl -pe 's/E\K([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02d", 1+$1/e' file
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/ProgramName%20S01E02/0/99/0">ProgramName</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E02/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E60/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program%20Name%20S01E86/0/99/0">Program Name</A>
```

You can add the `-i` option to make changes in-place. I would recommend creating backup before doing so.

Comment: You've gotta love perl one-liners! :)

jaypal, thank you so very much for an elegant solution!

Comment: The case where the code reaches `E99/` is not covered, so what happens after that?

Comment: @LaughDonor It can be handled with little extra code but when OP says his file does not contain numbers over 90, I chose to believe him. ('E01/' in most lines in the HTML file and will always be between '01' and '90'.). But for completeness this could be used in such cases - `perl -pe 's/E\K([0-9]+)/sprintf "%02d", ($1<90?1+$1:$1)/e' file`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed` inside BASH as a fantastic one-liner, either:

```
sed -ri 's/(.*E)([0-9]{2})(\/.*)/printf "\1%02u\3" $((10#\2+(10#\2>=90?0:1)))/ge' FILENAME
```

or if you are guaranteed the number is lower than 100:

```
sed -ri 's/(.*E)([0-9]{2})(\/.*)/printf "\1%02u\3" $((10#\2+1)))/ge' FILENAME
```

Basically, you'll be doing inplace search and replace. The above will not add anything after 90 (since you didn't specify the exact nature of the overflow condition). So `E89/` -> `E90/`,  `E90/` -> `E90/`, and if by chance you have `E91/`, it will remain `E91/`. Add this line inside a loop for multiple files

A small explanation of the above command:

- **-r** states that you'll be using a regular expression
- **-i** states to write back to the same file (be careful with overwriting!)
- **s/search/replace/ge** this is the regex command you'll be using

  - **s/** states you'll be using a string search
  - **(.*E)*** first grouping of all characters upto the first E (case sensitive)
  - **([0-9]{2})** second grouping of numbers 0 through 9, repeated twice (fixed width)
  - **(/.)** third grouping getting the escaped trailing slash and everything after that
  - **/ (slash separator)** denotes end of search pattern and beginning of replacement pattern
  - **printf "format" var** this is the expression used for each replacement
  - **\1** place first grouping found here
  - **%02u** the replace format for the *var*
  - **\3** place third grouping found here
  - **$((expression))** BASH arithmetic expression to use in printf format
  - **10#\2** force second grouping as a base 10 number
  - **+(10#\2>=90?0:1)** add 0 or 1 to the second grouping based on if it is >= 90 (as used in first command)
  - **+1** add 1 to the second grouping (see second command)
  - **/ge** flags for *global* replacement and the replace parameter will be an *expression*

GNU `sed` and `awk` are very powerful tools to do this sort of thing.

Comment: AndieBou, I very much appreciate your time, and effort and especially explaining what the command line is supposed to be doing however the sed one-liner doesn't work under OS X as it's BSD sed doesn't have the -r option. I also tried it under RHEL 6.5 and it chops off everything after '<DT><A HREF="https://domain.com/search/Program' while adding a bit of garbage and generating numerous errors to stdout.

For now I'm going to use jaypal's perl one-liner as it works as is.  When I have the time, I try to debug the sed one-liner as I always like having multiple ways to accomplish any given task.

Comment: For BSD sed you can use `-E`. It doesn't have all the GNU goodies but gets a little closer.

Comment: jaypal thanks, I did try with -E and it still threw errors, didn't like /ge and using just /g the output was corrupted.  I would have mentioned this in my reply to AndieBou however I was limited to the number of characters in the reply.  Setting aside running under OS X the sed one-liner didn't work as written under RHEL 6.5 either.  Your perl one-liner works as is and I have also modified it to address another occasional need in a different script.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as one line sed!
Break the commands used into multiple commands and you can debug your bash or grep or sed.

```
# find the number
# use -o to grep to just return pattern
# use head -n1 for safety to just get 1 number
n=$(grep -o "E[0-9][0-9]\/" file.html |grep -o "[0-9][0-9]"|head -n1)
#octal 08 and 09 are problem so need to do this
n1=10#$n
echo Debug n1=$n1 n=$n

n2=n1
# bash arithmetic done inside (( ))
# as ever with bash bracketing whitespace is needed
(( n2++ ))
echo debug n2=$n2

# use sed with -i -e for inline edit to replace number
sed -ie "s/E$n\//E$(printf '%02d' $n2)\//" file.html
grep "E[0-9][0-9]" file.html
```

awk might be better. Maybe could do it in one awk command also.

The sed one-liner in other answer is awesome :-)

This works in bash or sh.

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: I believe the "`" at the end of head -n1 is a typo?

Comment: Thanks slebetman. Removed it. I'm testing with sh only as I'm using android phone shell :-E and don't have bash at the moment.

Comment: The original code gaoithe posted did not work however I then saw it was edited and with the edited code and the '"`" at the end of head -n1 is a typo?' removed the code does work.  gaoithe, thank you for taking the time to provide a working solution, although not as elegant as jaypal's perl one-liner nonetheless I do appreciate what you've provided as I always learn more when being able to take different approaches.  @slebetman thanks for confirming the typo as it matched the output... unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Comment: I'm learning too! Certainly not as elegant but I hope as it is broken down a bit it can be followed a bit easier. The sed one-liner and this answer have a few similarities. The base 10 conversion was needed to avoid trouble with invalid octal 08 and 09. Sorry about typo! :-( Copy and paste sh to bash style. I could only test with sh.

Comment: Pure shell scripts are always useful even if you can do better in perl. There are times when you can't rely on perl or ruby or python being installed. For example if you are in charge of maintaining the build and install scripts for perl or ruby or python :)